# CommonJS require not working when the module name is dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, commonjs

I have the following code which is working fine

```
var angular = require("angular");

module.exports = angular
    .module('controllers', [])
    .controller('Topbar', require('../controllers/Topbar'));
```

But when I change it to the following code such that the `require` is done by a separate 'utility' function called `r` which automatically appends the folder name, I am getting errors.

```
var angular = require("angular");
var r = function (a) {
    return require('../controllers/'+ a)
}
module.exports = angular
    .module('controllers', [])
    .controller('Topbar', r('Topbar'));
```

[image]

Comment: Any updates? Are you still facing this problem?

Comment: @CosminAbabei Yep

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem into a fiddle so we can have a look?